# Would like to write a javascript that helps me to find documents in a folder

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I would like to write a js for an offline website (located on a local Windows server or any other server). It's supposed to look for files like PDFs in several directories and display them as search result on the "website", which isn't a real website, since it's on a local server and not in the web. The PDF is supposed to open in the browser after clicking it. I already have this kind of search engine as a php file, which I wrote with some help from friends. I also want to share this site with other friends. Basically I'll send them the whole folder with the html - document (or the .php site), so they can use it to search for certain pdfs in the folder. Its like a offline wiki for medical research documents. But I don't want them to always install php on their local servers, so they can run my php-searchmachine, thus I need to write it new as a javascript. By google and stack overflow I came across this solution https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/find+file+in+directory+javascript but it seems like that this needs node.js, so all have to install node.js, which is similar to installing php, I guess (im not familiar with node.js). Also I'm not sure if node.js is running on a normal client or server, which is not a webserver.

How can I start with such a project? Is javascript the correct attempt to solve this?

Comment: I think you should use node.js and bundle your html code with electron, that way they don't have to install anything and node.js can help you find the files using the ```fs``` lib in node.js

Comment: @ikben thanks for your response. I will read something about electron to get familiar with it. Will they still be able to edit the html and css after bundling it with electron by themself? With a regular editor like VS code?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Search has the ability to search PDF contents when boosted by a PDF (index) iFilter, this means the user can search and find instantly a new search word or a saved search it took only a second to hand enter this search (actually took longer to save for double click next time) just for illustration I chose a word I knew was in one file and actually found it is also in  two other PDFs.
[image]

The problem for your JS coding is how to use JavaScript to interface with Windows Search since using explorer I could not run that search on a remote server shared library drive (I could see their contents as per second screen but for search, had to pull a local library copy down to my documents) and that is where your JS skills come into play. Personally I would avoid JS and use a VLC method to share view via a remote Lan server or simpler invoke a plain text indexed local copy of remote files for download as and when required.

[image]